# Shader Graph, add color outline to 2D Sprite

Tags: unity, shaders

I'm having trouble creating a shader in Unity Shader Graph (2D) that fills the image from the bottom to the top and adds a color outline along the visible part of the sprite.

I can fill the image and that seems to be working. I can't however add the color outline. I figured it has something to do with using the inverse alpha of an image, but since i'm pretty new to shaders in general I find it hard to implement it.

This is what i currently have:

[image: Shader Graph]

As you can see I have the substract node there for the inverse alpha. I'm pretty stuck as to where to go next. I cannot seeme to find a relevant tutorial online. I tried implementing a Fresnel effect, but that seems to only apply to 3D images (i had tried to replace the Master with a PBR master and attaching the fresnel, but it had no effect).

What would be the correct approach from here to add the color outline to the sprite, taking in account the vertical fill?

Comment: How thick an outline do you need? In a shader, each pixel is being drawn in parallel, so the only way for a pixel to know it should draw itself in the outline colour is for it to read the texture for all its nearby neighbours, to figure out if it's within half a line thickness of the edge. The thicker your line, the more texture samples, which can get expensive. If you need something thicker than a pixel or two, you might want to consider pre-baking a signed distance field texture for each sprite, which lets you answer "how close am I to the edge" with just one sample.

Comment: I want the outline a few pixels in size I guess. It needs to be visually present and I would like to add bloom in post processing with it. 
Howeveer, the things you mention seem to go over my head.